# How to use remote files for classes/etc with Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm test SciTe editor, and Gosu for ruby game development. I decided to make a class to control my sprites. The class was written in a separate .rb file, in the same folder as the main .rb file. However, I can't use `Sprite.new` in the main file. How can I do that?

Comment: (That's not really a "remote" file; remote almost always implies it's on a separate machine. This would be an "external" file, or library, or something.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '', 'MyFile')
```

I don't know why. But just `require` simply doesn't always work on different OS. But the above code always works for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'sprite'
```

(Or whatever it's called.)

As Frederick notes, if you're using Ruby 1.9, the current directory isn't automatically part of the load path (not sure if I agree with the decision). You can add it on the command line like this:

```
ruby -I. main.rb
```

Comment: Neither 'system' 'System' 'System.rb' 'system.rb' seem to work. "No such file to load"

Comment: @Omega Then you need to provide more info, like the actual file/directory structure, how you're running it, etc.

Comment: Well, all I did was: Install Gosu using RubyGems, and then I made two .rb text files in a folder in my desktop. I am editing both using SciTe. That is all, really. I got this error: C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': no such file to load -- System.rb (LoadError)
 from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
 from Game.rb:2:in `<main>'

Comment: @Omega Running from the command line? The `Sprite` class is in a file named `System.rb` (w/ the upper-case `"S"`)? (It's counter to convention to name the files w/ an uppercase, although I don't *think* that's the issue--I'm never sure with Windows though.)

Comment: You do also need to make sure tht the folder containing sprite.rb is in Ruby's load path (by default . isn't in 1.9)

Comment: @Frederick Cheung: What is this "Ruby's load path"?

Comment: @Omega It's the load path used by Ruby to determine where to look for files. As Frederick says, in Ruby 1.9, the current directory isn't on it by default. See updated answer.

Comment: Wait, I don't use the command line. I'm using SciTe to run my file

Comment: @Omega Then you'll need to see how scite configures its execution environment.